# Clear buffer on javascript's Websocket

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, buffer

I am trying to write javacript to receive a mjpeg using Websocket.
The client can choose the video file to play.

The server is sending mjpeg as image one by one using  json as following:
{"image":"base64_image"}

The problem occurs when client tries to choose the different video.
It takes more than 2mins to change to the new video file.
( the server and client are in different country though.)

I know there is the delay but the thing is

> The longer time I open the previous video file, the slower the next video file got shown.

I guess there is data queuing in the buffer. So, my question is

> How can I clear that socket buffer in javascript?

or if it's not about buffer, any idea of what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Without any example code most likely the issue is that your websocket client is getting flooded by the fire-hose coming in from the server.

Most likely you could adjust for this by having the websocket client poll for the next frame when it is ready to handle it.  The benefit to this is that you could then stop polling for the frames for asset X and start polling for the frames from asset Y.

That of course assumes the issue is client side... if it is on your server that it loading up the whole video etc and can't "let go" of the video to switch to the other then that is a different issue on the server.

That said, this is not a very good use case for websockets... they are great for small data packets... is this just an experiment?

Comment: That would be slower and double latency by sending back and forth. Now, I am trying to do image processing using opencv from server and send processed image to the client. Do you have any suggestion beside websocket to match this work?

Comment: @A-letubby - I currently run a websocket (ws) application that uses this "polling" mechanism over ws, I think if you did a simple test you'd find that the "ACK" or "POLL" message up from the client is very very quick over the ws since the connection is already open.  If you were polling over standard HTTP then yes it would be slow because you are opening and closing a lot of connections.

In general ws is not well suited to sending large images/packets, it would be better to re-envision this and send the URL for the file down the ws and let the browser load the image via normal channels. (XHR)

Comment: @NickSharp Hi, i am doing something similar with OpenCV and Web-Sockets. Did you get a resolution as to how to clear or set the buffer space?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - I'm not sure there was actually a buffer space.  My suggestion would still be to implement some for of poll, even if it was only every 100 frames to send up a "still listening" to the server.  In the OP's case it seemed like he was just flooding himself.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - also, Websockets are not the best for pulling down the asset.  If anything keep the socket about communication, and use more traditional HTTP GET's to pull down the raw asset or processed file.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I did prior to using sockets use http gets and the performance was poor compared to sockets. Also pulling down a byte array automatically converts it to base64 where as I prefer to convert to base64 on the client side. I was thinking about a pulse hello from client to server every 30 secs or so to check whether client was picking up